# AutoFill vs FillDown: what's the difference?

Tags: vba

**AutoFill**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill
**FillDown**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown

What are the difference between the two?

The description of AutoFill in the MS documentation is: "Performs an autofill on the cells in the specified range."
Totally useless...

Comment: Did you try them on a test worksheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Autofill**

```
expression.AutoFill (Destination, Type)
```

The type parameter controls how the information is going to be copied onto the destination cells. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilltype) lists them all. So you have control over whether only the values or formats or patterns of the source cells will be copied.

**For FillDown**

There is no such control.
And as the documentation quotes

> The **contents and formatting of the cell** or cells in the top row of a
>   range are copied into the rest of the rows in the range.

Comment: Thanks @Dilnoor.  Am I correct in assuming that AutoFill includes and is a superset of FillDown?  for example range("a1:a5").FillDown is like shorthand of range("a1").AutoFill range("a1:a5"), xlFillCopy?